# How to make certain part of raster as no data with other overlapping raster?

Tags: raster-calculator, masking, nodata

I have two rasters, one raster contains all the ground features (roads, buildings, Trees etc) and another raster contains only man made features (Roads, buildings etc). I would like to have raster output which will have no data or 0 values where 2nd raster overlaps 1st raster.

I tried SetNull tool but no luck so far.  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a binary raster out of Raster 2, where all manmade feature pixels are equal to 0 and everything else is equal to 1.

Then multiply this binary raster with Raster 1. Everywhere your ground features overlap with a road the pixel will be set to 0, otherwise it will be left as is (possibly a value, possibly 0 or whatever Raster 1's no data value is).

Comment: thanks a lot it worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Great to hear. When you receive an answer that solves your problem Accept it (click the check mark underneath the voting buttons) so that other people know that solution works.